# Get second column of a data frame using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Pandas in Python and I am having some difficulties returning the second column of a dataframe without column names just numbers as indexes.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

directory = 'A://'
sample = 'test.txt'

# Test with Air Sample
fileAir = os.path.join(directory,sample)

dataAir = pd.read_csv(fileAir,skiprows=3)

print(dataAir.iloc[:,1])
```

The data I am working with would be similar to:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Then, using pandas I wanted to have only

```
[[2,2,2]].
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
dataframe_name[column_index].values
```

like

```
df[1].values
```

or

```
dataframe_name['column_name'].values
```

like

```
df['col1'].values
```